# When Google Mobile Vision will support the face recognition login for Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, face-recognition

Based on Google Mobile Vision where I can get detailed information, examples, etc… about flutter_mobile_vision Detect Faces coordinates? I am trying to build a demo app with a face recognition login. Can I achieve this with flutter_mobile_vision? If yes, how? If not, when Flutter will support the face recognition login?

In Google Mobile Vision https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts the Face Recognition page I get information like;

Face recognition automatically determines if two faces are likely to correspond to the same person. Note that at this time, the Google Face API only provides functionality for face detection and not face recognition.

Can I use face detection as face recognition to build a login?

Comment: _"Can I use face detection as a face recognition to build a login?"_ That seems like a bad idea, since all you be able to tell is that something was found that looks like a face. You won't know whose face it is.

Comment: @Michael thanks. The documentation so confusing. It says face recognition and talks about face detection and coordinates. So, I assume something is missing or misleading and try to get right answer.